# Bison how to write a rule?

Tags: bison, bisonc++

I have a rule like this:

`A -->   a  B C d` , where  `a, d` are terminal symbols
and `B, C` are non-terminal symbols.

```
B -->   a1 | a2 | a3
C -->   a4 | a5 | a6
```

I have write this rule in bison:

```
  my_rule:
            a B C d   {   handler->handle_B_C(handle_B($2), handle_C($3)); }
  B :
      a1 { $$ = ONE; }
    | a2 { $$ = TWO; }
    | a3 { $$ = THREE; }
    ;
  C:
         a4 { $$ = FOUR; } 
      | a5  { $$ = FIVE; }
      | a6  { $$ = SIX  }
```

I would like wrtie this rule like this:

```
   A --> a B
   A --> errorCase
   B --> a1 C | a2 C | a3 C
   B --> errorCase
   C --> a4 D | a5 D | a6D
   D --> d
   D -->errorCase
```

But I have no idea how to write it in bison. Can anyone help me to write it in bison?
(I have no idea how I should get the value of the B and D)

Comment: Careful of tagging; flex-lexer is for the lexical analyzer; flex is for the Adobe/Apache UI Framework.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Error-Recovery.html#Error-Recovery . Don't modify your grammar. Just insert error recovery rules.

Comment: [richi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1566221/rici) I don't want to continue when the error occurs, I just want to report proper error message.

Comment: You don't have to recover from an error recovery rule :) Also see this essay by Russ Cox: http://research.swtch.com/yyerror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following grammar is accepted by yacc(BSD) without any problems.  It should work with bison(Linux) as well.

By general convention, the tokens are usually capitalized and rules are in lower case.

```
%token A A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 D

%%

a
    : A b {
        $$ = node($1, $2);
    }
    ;

b
    : A1 c {
        $$ = node($1, $2);
    }
    | A2 c {
         $$ = node($1, $2);
    }
    | A3 c {
         $$ = node($1, $2);
    }
    ;

c
    : A4 d {
         $$ = node($1, $2);
    }
    | A5 d {
         $$ = node($1, $2);
    }
    | A6 d {
         $$ = node($1, $2);
    }
    ;

d
    : D {
        $$ = node($1);
    }
    ;
%%

#include <stdio.h>

void yyerror(const char *s)
{
    fflush(stdout);
    fprintf(stderr, "*** %s\n", s);
}
```